# Checking pass field in post data [NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, validation, rest

I'm having a problem passing post data in node js. I already know how this works but i don't know how to validate the fields in the post data.

Example:

If I pass the json `{"userInfo":"myusername"}` my server accepts it. 
But if I pass a json with invalid format like this `{"usersInfo":"myusername"}` my server is crashing. My goal is before receiving the data i need to check the fields if it is valid and  if not I will send a 400 Bad Request status code `res.writeHead(400);`

```
    app.post('/api/adduser', function(req, res) {

         var userInfo = req.body.userInfo;

         //code goes here

    });
```

Is there any way on how to do this? Thanks guys.

Comment: When is your server crashing? I suspect it does when you try to use the data that was posted so it should be possible for you to detect the bad data and respond accordingly as Jonathan mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum you ought to check to see if req.body.userInfo is defined.

```
app.post('/api/adduser', function(req, res) {
     if( typeof req.body.userInfo === "undefined" ) {
         // error code here
     } else {
         // add-user code goes here
     }
});
```

I would advise against using `userInfo == undefined` because you're just creating a crack for bugs to crawl in. Don't go there.

A more robust solution would be to use a validation module. There are a few different validators for node.js. What you choose will depend on your tastes and what framework you're using (express, restify, etc.). A validator is really beyond the scope of your original question, but you know, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

If your key could be named differently you could check for it being undefined:

```
if(userInfo == undefined){
    res.writeHead(400)
}
```